# No se envía el email

Tags: php

No logro que se envíe el email, no sé que estoy haciendo mal pero entre más reviso no se que pasa... Estoy usando 000webhost con PHP 7.2

```js
<?php

$email = "email@email.com";
$message = "Hi";

if (// SI LAS INSTRUCCIONES SE CUMPLEN) {

$email_post = $email;
$asunto = "Repost";
$msg = $message;
$header = "From: example@example.com" . "\r\n\";
$header.= "Reply-To: example@example.com" . "\r\n\";
$header.= "X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion();

mail($email_post,$asunto,$message,$header);

}

?>
```

Comment: Desde el servidor local no te va a dejar enviar emails. Una alternativa es utilizar [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) para que tu servidor local deje de ser local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede que las barras `\` al final de los dos primeros `$header` lo que estén haciendo sea **escapar las comillas dobles que le siguen**.

Aparte de eso, conviene que completes tu código, poniendo un `else` donde verifiques que las condiciones de que hablas se cumplen o no. Y verificando igualmente si el envío del mensaje falla concretamente. Y también, conviene que limpies el código de variables reduntantes, si ya tienes el correo electrónico en `$email` no tiene sentido esto: `$email_post = $email;` ni esto: `$msg = $message;`, simplemente usa `$mail` y `$message`, ¿por qué creas variables con otras variables que ya existen?

Así debería funcionar, o al menos informarte con mayor precisión de lo que ocurre.

```
$email = "email@email.com";
$message = "Hi";

if (// SI LAS INSTRUCCIONES SE CUMPLEN) {
    $asunto = "Repost";
    $header = "From: example@example.com" . "\r\n";
    $header.= "Reply-To: example@example.com" . "\r\n";
    $header.= "X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion();
    
    if ( mail($email,$asunto,$message,$header) ) {
        $outPut="Mensaje enviado. Si no lo ves revisa la carpeta SPAM";
    } else {
        $outPut="No se envió el mensaje. Revisa tu configuración de email en PHP";
    }        
} else {
    $outPut="Las condiciones no se cumplen";
}
echo $outPut;
```

Prueba de este modo y nos dices qué se cuenta `$outPut`. No escribas código donde queden aspectos sin cubrir. Luego el código no dice nada y no sabes por qué.