# Función mail en PHP y sus parámetros

Tags: php, php7, email, phpmailer, php8

PHP mail function: parameters: `$to, $subject, $message` en realidad son variables, ¿cierto? ¿Por qué debo usar esos nombres siempre? ¿es por convención, buenas prácticas o algo así? ¿Qué pasa si uso, por ejemplo:

```
$email_destination; //en lugar de $to.
$topic; //en lugar de $subject.
$body_text; //en lugar de $message.
```

Si uso eso, ¿el mail function no se ejecutará? Mi confusión se debe a que aprendí que tú puedes nombrar a las variables como quieras, excepto las superglobales, pero en este caso veo `$to, $subject, $message` en todos los tutoriales, como algo impuesto por PHP, hasta en el mismo sitio de php.net lo menciona. ¿Acaso son VARIABLES RESERVADAS en PHP y hay que usarlas necesariamente?

Comment: *¿Por qué debo usar esos nombres siempre?* No hay ningún lugar que mencione que **debes** usar esos nombres siempre, puedes usar los nombres que quieras, pruébalo y verás ... ([aquí un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/486881/29967)) aunque, por claridad en el código deberías usar siempre nombres que refieran a lo que estás declarando.

Comment: Pensaba que sí debía usarlos porque en TODAS partes, en todos los tutoriales lo veo así, con esos ejemplos, incluso en el mismo sitio de php.net como si fuera algo impuesto, buen aclaración.

Comment: Puedes nombrar las variables como desees, lo realmente importante es la información que le asignas a cada una y el orden en el que las pasas a la función.

Comment: No es algo impuesto, simplemente el sitio de PHP usa por lo general  convención de nombre en inglés y por eso pone las variables en inglés, aun en el idioma español. En realidad, no es una mala idea implementar convención de nombre en inglés, aunque sea un proyecto destinado a otro idioma, hay varias ventajas: el inglés permite variables más cortas, es un lenguaje universal, lo cual es una gran ventaja si es un proyecto colaborativo donde intervienen varios programadores de distintos países, etc ...

Comment: Probaste qué pasa si haces lo que dices como ejemplo? Si es así, qué pasó?

Answer (score 1):

Al momento de utilizar un método, lo que real mente importa es el orden de los `parámetros`  y si dicho `parámetro es requerido  o no`   :

**¿Qué pasa si cambio el nombre a la variable que paso como parámetro en una función?**  -Nada, la función continuara ejecutándose.

Un ejemplo la función mail :

En la documentación de la función  la encontraras e la siguiente manera

```php
mail(
    string $to,
    string $subject,
    string $message,
    string $additional_headers = ?,
    string $additional_parameters = ?
):
```

Tu la puedes llamar  de la siguiente manera:

```php
<?php
  $para      = 'nobody@example.com';
  $titulo    = 'El título';
  $mensaje   = 'Hola';
  $cabeceras = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
      'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
      'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

  mail($para, $titulo, $mensaje, $cabeceras);
?>
```

puedes observar que en la llamada a la función  los nombres de los parámetros son diferentes e incluso estan es castellano. también hace falta un parámetro `$additional_parameters`  el cual es opcional.

**¿ Como identificar si un parámetro es opcional en un método?**
Los parámetros opcionales  en la documentación tienen asignado un valor por defecto  `$additional_parameters = ?`  o `$additional_parameters = ""`  o bien `$additional_parameters = array()`

**¿Tendré un error en mi código si no envió  un parámetro opcional en una función?**
-No tendía por que ocurrir un error de programación.